# How do I emulate Python's named printf parameters in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, string, printf

In Python, you can do this:

```
print "Hi!  I'm %(name)s, and I'm %(age)d years old." % ({"name":"Brian","age":30})
```

What's the closest, simplest Ruby idiom to replicate this behavior?  (No monkeypatching the String class, please.)

One of the really excellent benefits of this is that you can store the pre-processed string in a variable and use it as a "template", like so:

```
template = "Hi!  I'm %(name)s, and I'm %(age)d years old."
def greet(template,name,age):
    print template % ({"name":name,"age":age})
```

This is obviously a trivial example, but there is a lot of utility in being able to store such a string for later use.  Ruby's `"Hi!  I'm #{name}"` convention is cursorily similar, but the immediate evaluation makes it less versatile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use

```
printf "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s\n", {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
```

or

```
data = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
printf "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s\n",  data
```

or (this needs ruby 1.9, for the other examples I'm not sure)

```
data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}
printf "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s\n", data
```

This prints

```
1: value1 2: value2
```

Important restriction: The used keys of the hash (*data* in my example) must be symbols.

---

A remark on the example above:
`printf` takes one format string and optional parameters. But there is also a `String#%`-method.

The following four calls have all the same result:

```
printf "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s\n" , {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
printf "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s\n" % {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
print  "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s\n" % {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
puts   "1: %<key1>s 2: %<key2>s"   % {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
```

The second version uses first the `String#%`-method and sends the result to `printf`.

Answer (score 15):

you do it like this:

```
values = {:hello => 'world', :world => 'hello'}
puts "%{world} %{hello}" % values
```

Read this for more info:
http://ruby.runpaint.org/strings#sprintf-hash

If you need something more sophisticated, read about ERB, and google template engines.
If you need to generate web pages, emails etc. you'll find that using template engines is a more robust solution.

Comment: Actually, this works if you change the keys in the `values` hash to Symbols instead of Strings: `values = {:hello => 'world', :world => 'hello'}`. See the last sentence in [@knut's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12563022/504611).

Comment: you should probably add that gotcha to your answer @Michael.

Answer (score 6):

There are some nice trick to this in Ruby:

```
name = "Peter"
@age = 15 # instance variable
puts "Hi, you are #{name} and your age is #@age"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 class Template

  def %(h)
    "Hi!  I'm #{h[:name]}s, and I'm #{h[:age]}d years old."


  end
end
```

Then call it with

```
t=Template.new
t%({:name => "Peter", :age => 18})
```

This is not exactly what you asked for but could give you a hint.

Answer (score 2):

In a double-quoted string in Ruby, you can insert the result of a Ruby expression like this:

```
puts "Hi!  I'm #{name}, and I'm #{age} years old."
```

Just put an expression inside the curly braces. (It could also be something more complex like #{age + 5}, or #{name + ' ' + last_name}, or a function call.)

Answer (score 2):

What works (meanwhile), though, is something along the lines of:

```
d = {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"}
s = "string to be magically induced with variables, which are \n * %s and \n * %s.\n"
print s%d.values()
# or
print s%[d["key1"], d["key2"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

puts "Hi! I'm #{name}, and I'm #{age} years old."